# element selection in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I subset the required array from original array(data) converting other element as np.nan?

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5])

required = np.where((data <= 2) & (data >= 4),data,np.nan)

print (required)
```

The required array must be as follows:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,nan,nan,nan,4,4,4,5,5,5]
```

Comment: As a side note, your desired output is impossible (except by using `dtype=object`), because `nan` is a `float`, and cannot be stored in an `int` array. So, you can have `[1., 1., …, nan, …, 5., 5.]`, but not `[1, 1, …, nan, …, 5, 5]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `or`, not `and` (or, here, `|` not `&`):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5])
>>> required = np.where((data <= 2) | (data >= 4),data,np.nan)
>>> required
array([  1.,   1.,   1.,   2.,   2.,   2.,  nan,  nan,  nan,   4.,   4.,
         4.,   5.,   5.,   5.])
```

Comment: Yep, `data <= 2` and `data >= 4` isn't possible for any value of `data`, so he ends up with all `nan`s…